# Opening ports in OSX Yosemite for development servers without switching off the Firewall

Tags: port, osx-yosemite

In OSX Yosemite I need two ports opened, port 8080 for my Dart Server and 8081 for a Tomcat Server.
I basically want to fire up a browser on an Android/Apple phone/tablet and on a Windows Desktop, point it to `10.0.0.3:8080` and see the output of `pub serve` and that page will then be firing AJAX requests to `10.0.0.3:8081` - mostly for testing how my web app looks like in other browsers.

The UI only allows adding applications as shown in this screenshot

[image]

So unless I've missed something in the control panel, how would I open up those ports via command line? I don't see an iptables command like I have on Debian.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142778/how-to-open-a-specific-port-in-firewall-os-x-10-9-4 may help

Comment: `pfctl` seems to be the correct command, `ipfw` is deprecated, post the complete `pfctl` line that will open the relevant port and I'll accept as the correct answer.